# resultCode -1 -Android

Tags: android, android-intent

Why is my resultCode -1 for this camera intent when i take a photo and click the tick?

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            imageUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"fname_" +        
                                    String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg"));
            intent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
            startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It means that finished activity worked correctly http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#RESULT_OK.